# On an example of an infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(f(n)\right)^{B_n}$, where $B_n$ is the $nth$ Bernoulli number for $n\geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convergence-divergence, infinite-product, bernoulli-numbers

In the past I've known the post [1] from MathOverflow, and I am curious about if is known or you can to create an infinite product (converging) in a same way for an (arithmetic) function $f(n)$ as the basis of our factors and with exponents $B_n$ the Bernoulli numbers for $n\geq 1$. See this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html) if you need the definition of this sequence.

> **Question.** Is feasible to define a convergent infinite product 
>   $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(f(n)\right)^{B_n},$$ for a suitable $f(x)$, being $B_n$ the Bernoulli numbers? If you can not create such example and there are well known examples from the literature refer the literature and I try find it. **Many thanks.**

Only is required an example showing convergence, thus isn't required a closed-form. If you show a didactic way to find examples it is good, but isn't required.

I presume that I need to take logarithms and work with some asymptotic for the Bernoulli numbers. See the following codes using Wolfram Alpha online calculator if you want

`prod n^(Bernoulli(n)), from n=1 to 14`

`prod n^(Bernoulli(n)), from n=1 to 16`

`prod n^(Bernoulli(n)), from n=1 to 18`

thus I suspect that choose $f(n)=n$ is a bad way.

### References:

[1] [$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{\mu(n)}=\frac{1}{4 \pi ^2}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124308/prod-n-1-infty-n-mun-frac14-pi-2), from MathOverflow.

Comment: The trivial example would be $f(n) = 1$. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: For convergence of the infinite product, you need  at least $f(n)^{B_n} \to 1$

Comment: Many thanks I think that is better infinte products different of $1$ or $0$. Any case many thanks. I believe that there are examples in the literature, where the Bernoulli numbers are as factors of our infinite product, but not in the exponent. My intention/goal is learn how to create an interesting product with the same form of the reference of MathOverflow, since the Möbius function and the Bernoulli numbers capture valuable information @orlp

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution @GEdgar

Comment: This means $f(n) \to 1$ quite quickly, at least for even $n$.

Comment: Also note, even that $\mu$ thing is not convergent.  That other problem is some sort of "regularized" infinite product.

Comment: Many thanks @GEdgar I try think in it. If you want to add some remarks about how  to explore an infinite product of the kind that you evoke (in your words "regularized") sure that some user understand your calculations and interesting reasonings. On the other 
 hand I hope some answers for my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments $f(n)=1$ is convergent to $1$,

Also since $B_{2n} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1} 2 (2n)!}{ (2 \pi)^{2n}} \zeta(2n)$

It then follows from $\zeta \to 1$  $(n \to \infty)$ and Stirling's formula that

$|B_{2n}| \approx 4 \sqrt{n \pi} (\frac{n}{e \pi})^{2n} $,

So the family of all functions of the form $f(n) = n^{g(n)}$ such that $ g(n) << \frac{1}{ 4 \sqrt{n \pi} (\frac{n}{e \pi})^{2n} * n^{1+\epsilon} \ln^2 n} $ for all $\epsilon >0$.

Will be convergent, easily be showing that $\sum \limits_{ n =1}^{\infty} B_n \ln f(n) = \sum \limits_{ n =1}^{\infty} g(n) B_n  \ln n  \leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon} \ln^2 n} \ln n $ which is obviously convergent each to a different value.

Comment: Sorry by the confusion but I believe that to get a LHS convegenct (in the last calculation) your condition sould be $g(n) << \frac{1}{ 4 \sqrt{n \pi} (\frac{n}{e \pi})^{2n} * n^{1+\delta} \ln^2 n}$ for some $\delta>0$.

Comment: @user243301 you are correct, i will edit, but remeber that $B_n$ alters between negative and positive signs, while i took it to the extreme, i think it could converge even for more loose condition.